# ssh: connect to host xxxx@xxxx.in in port 22 : connection timed out

Tags: 12.04, openssh

I am new to Linux and SSH. when I try to connect to a remote grid computer (for which I have access) I am getting connection timed out error. I have recently installed Ubuntu in my system. I also have OpenSSH client and server. Port 22 is enabled and I can access localhost.

Kindly give me a step by step procedure to solve the problem, as I am new to this whole thing.

regards

Comment: Post the output of `ssh -vvv host:port`

Comment: output is Open SSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.01c 10May 2012 debug1: reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config               debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line19: Applying option for *           debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0                                      ssh: could not resolve hostname (my host name:port no): name or service not known

Comment: Is the address valid, are you able to ping to that address?

Comment: The address is valid. my boss is able to connect from his system.

Comment: Clearly the hostname does not resolve into an ip. Can you post the output of 'host yourhostname' (f.e. host my_server.com) or use ip instead of yourhostname when you ssh into the server?

Comment: can you ping the server from your machine? (with IP and name)

Answer (score 3):

Try to check if port 22 is listening:

```
sudo netstat -alnp|grep :22
```

Try to allow port in ufw

```
sudo ufw allow 22

sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable
```

Try to add port into iptables

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Is port forwarded?

Comment: how do i know whether the port is forwarded ?

Comment: These instructions are to check if the server is working and to open firewall on the server but the problem is the client not reaching the server (name resolution problem as seen in comments on Question) and other people are able to connect so I don't think it would be wise to change things on the server at 1st attempt.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all of your `iptables` and etc.

Maybe your network Administrator block the port 22 on the LAN switches or change the default ssh port to other number, So check it by him.